# How can I download hdf5 files from URLs in R?

Tags: r, curl, hdf5, satellite, satellite-image

I am trying to download a large number of HDF5 files to my computer from URLs provided by NASA's Earthdata Search. A [download script](https://search.earthdata.nasa.gov/downloads/4024660023) (third tab) is provided by NASA, but since the rest of this project is written in R, I have been trying to translate this script into R as well. It *appears* to work in that it creates files with the expected names, but they are not valid HDF5 files when I then go to open them.

My current code (requires Earthdata log-in credentials to reproduce):

```
library(curl)
library(httr)

cookiejar <- tempfile(fileext = ".cookies")
netrc <- tempfile(fileext = ".netrc")

prompt_credentials <- function() {
  cat("Enter your Earthdata Login or other provider supplied credentials\n")
  username <- readline("Username (dylan.titmuss): ")
  username <- ifelse(nchar(username) == 0, "dylan.titmuss", username)
  password <- readline("Password: ")
  cat(paste("machine urs.earthdata.nasa.gov login", username, "password", password), file = netrc)
  cat("\n")
}

exit_with_error <- function(msg) {
  cat("\nUnable to Retrieve Data\n\n", msg, "\n\nhttps://data.nsidc.earthdatacloud.nasa.gov/nsidc-cumulus-prod-protected/ATLAS/ATL07/006/2023/06/20/ATL07-02_20230620165624_00082001_006_01.h5\n\n")
  quit(save = "no", status = 1)
}

prompt_credentials()

detect_app_approval <- function() {
  res <- GET(
    url = "https://data.nsidc.earthdatacloud.nasa.gov/nsidc-cumulus-prod-protected/ATLAS/ATL07/006/2023/06/20/ATL07-02_20230620165624_00082001_006_01.h5",
    config = add_headers(`User-Agent` = "Mozilla/5.0"),
    cookies = cookiejar,
    verbose()
  )

  if (res$status_code != 200 && res$status_code != 301 && res$status_code != 302) {
    exit_with_error("Please ensure that you have authorized the remote application by visiting the link below ")
  }
}

setup_auth_curl <- function() {
  status <- GET(
    url = "https://data.nsidc.earthdatacloud.nasa.gov/nsidc-cumulus-prod-protected/ATLAS/ATL07/006/2023/06/20/ATL07-02_20230620165624_00082001_006_01.h5",
    config = add_headers(`User-Agent` = "Mozilla/5.0"),
    cookies = cookiejar,
    verbose()
  )

  if (status$status_code != 200 && status$status_code != 304) {
    detect_app_approval()
  }
}

fetch_urls <- function() {
  urls <- readLines(textConnection(urls_data))  # Assuming `urls_data` contains the list of URLs
  for (url in urls) {
    filename <- basename(url)
    stripped_query_params <- sub("\\?.*", "", filename)

    # Create a curl handle
    handle <- new_handle(
      useragent = "Mozilla/5.0",
      verbose = TRUE
    )

    # Perform the GET request
    response <- curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle)

    if (response$status_code == 200) {
      # Write the content to a file
      bin_file <- file(stripped_query_params, "wb")
      writeBin(response$content, bin_file)
      close(bin_file)
      
      cat("\n")
    } else {
      exit_with_error("Command failed with error. Please retrieve the data manually.")
    }
  }
}

urls_data <- c("https://data.nsidc.earthdatacloud.nasa.gov/nsidc-cumulus-prod-protected/ATLAS/ATL07/006/2023/06/20/ATL07-02_20230620165624_00082001_006_01.h5")
# other URLs are listed above

fetch_urls()

# Clean up temporary files
unlink(c(cookiejar, netrc))
```

I am very new to using the `curl` package, so I'm not particularly confident in the above code. Could the issue be with the `writeBin` function?